# Watch xml sent to jasper report

Tags: xml, jasper-reports, report, ireport

I'm using *JasperReports* and *iReport* to constructing some reports.

I'm trying to see what parameters are sent so I could use them in order to make the report more dynamic.

For example,  if a report is produced to Excel (and I'm sure there's a parameter in the *xml* for that) I will create a print expression not to show pages' numbers,  and if produced to *pdf*, it will print page numbers.

Any help?  Thanks in advance

PS:  I tried debugging to see what *xml* is produced but it's made on a web service which I cant see.

Comment: have you tried looking at it using firebug

Comment: @user2062262 Your question is unclear

Comment: @Gopinagh.R "I'm" is a perfectly valid form for "I am". No need to vandalize a question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there isn't anything in the XML file generated regarding the format you want to export to. The difference is that when you export to one format or another you use different classes/methods.

Anyway, if you want to show content depending on the output format, why don't you create your own parameter telling the report which output format will you be using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change report options after the report filling is done and the jasperprint object is made. The parameters are set before filling the report.

> For example, if a report is produced to Excel (and I'm sure there's a
>   parameter in the xml for that) I will create a print expression not to
>   show pages' numbers, and if produced to pdf, it will print page
>   numbers.

If you add another text/static field over your page number text field. That is if they overlap .Then the page number won't appear when you export to xls or any grid based export .But it will appear in pdf or in any non-grid based export .